# How to show scala doc from Java Editor in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, documentation, tooltip

I'm using the Akka Java API together with Eclipse (Kepler Service Release 2) + Maven. I can jump right into the scala class from the Java Editor, but I'm not able to see the documentation on hover (see example picture). Is there any way to include the documentation on hover?

On hover:

[image: Empty Hover Documentation]

The documentation it should display:

[image: Correct Documentation]

Comment: Do you still need an answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

When using maven convention, a library is bundled as 'group.artifact.version.jar' for binary, 'group.artifact.version-sources.jar' for source code and 'group.artifact.version-javadoc.jar' for docs. If you don't see the javadoc, then it means that the '-javadoc.jar' for that artifact is not pulled to local, in your case for the akka artifact. If you right click on the library, you should find an option to download javadoc under 'Maven' option. Once you download, you can see the javadoc.

Comment: I have the sources.jar and javadoc.jar installed in my .m2. In fact if I press F3 i can see the code and documentation. But, when type the code or press F2 on a method I can't get the documentation.